# Matching river direction with DTM using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, dem, rivers

I have rivers that some times they do not match their real direction based on the DTM, and they need to be flipped.

Is there any way to automatically match river direction based on the DTM in ArcGIS or any other software?

Output needs to be a shapefile, polyline.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/123008/2856

Comment: Its similar but not my case, i want the direction to match that DTM and not finding which lines doesn't create a route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution which worked was:

Convert rivers to 3D features based on the DTM, then added 2 fields calculating Z information with calculate geometry for the Start and End of the line, then calculate on a new field the difference  between Z of the starting line with the Z of end of the line, all the features with negative results (-5, -32.35, -65 etc..) have to be flipped.